# npx webpack is looking for webpack in a different module and throwing error

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am new to webpack and was going through webpack getting-started guide but when I try to run `npx webpack` it throws error:

```
'js\webpack-demo\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Abc\Dev\webpack\bin\webpack.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Lokking at the error, I can see that it is looking for webpack in `"Dev"` but I am currently in `"Dev/Web/webpack-demo"` and I have installed webpack locally here.

I have installed both webpack and webpack-cli.

Comment: do you have `node_modules` above in your directory tree? Seems it's something is confusing npx about where to look for the packages.

Comment: No, I don't but I cleaned some upper directory and tried running again and it ran. So there must be some files. Thanks for taking your time.